# SQL Server - Update value based another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have 2 tables :

Table1

- parcel_number
- pool_type

Table2

- parcel_number
- need_water

I would like to know if the table 1 "pool" column has a value than update the "need_water" column of the table 2 to yes.

Here what I would like to have for the table 2.

Table 1

| parcel_number | pool_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Circle |
| 2 | Oval |
| 3 | Null |
| 4 | Rectangular |

Table 2

| parcel_number | need_water |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | No |
| 4 | Yes |

```sql
 if exists(select a.pool_type 
 from table1 a
    where a.parcel_number = b.parcel_number)
    Begin
        Update b
        set b.need_water = 'Yes'
        from table2 b
        end
   else
    Begin
        Update b
        set b.need_water = 'No'
        from table2 b
    End
```

Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: We are using microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single update statement should be able to solve this:

```
UPDATE t2
    SET t2.need_water = CASE WHEN t1.parcel_number IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM table2 t2
   INNER JOIN table1 t1
   ON t2.parcel_number = t1.parcel_number
```

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE with a JOIN will work

```
UPDATE  t2
SET     need_water = 'yes'
FROM    Table1 t1
        JOIN Table2 t2
            ON t1.parcel_number = t2.parcel_number
WHERE   t1.pool_type IS NOT NULL
```